# Android: Button visible through overlapping fragment

Tags: java, android

i am a newbie so please keep that in mind.

I just added a fragment to my Main Activity (for the first time ever). The container for that fragment is a FrameLayout which i just put on top of the existing Relative Layout.
I can already switch between showing the fragment and removing it again.

There is only one problem: The buttons from the Main Activities' RelativeLayout are visible through the fragment, even though it has a background color.

Is there a simple way to get the buttons not showing through the fragment (but still be visible when i remove the fragment). I dont want to set them invisible and visible manually, because they only show up unter certain circumstances in the Main Activity.

One solution is probably, to replace the layout, that containts the buttons and everything else, with the fragment. But i wonder if there is a different solution because my Layout file is not set up properly to make that easily doable.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110067/android-fragments-overlapping?rq=1

Comment: Post your layout file - Views are drawn from top-to-bottom when it comes to XML defined layouts, so chances are you'll just need to shuffle around the position of your Button and FrameLayout so the FrameLayout appears after the Button.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the FrameLayout is already the last View within the Parent View. When i set a background color to that FrameLayout in the xml file, the buttons are still visible. Everything else is hidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone is intersted, i found the answer.

Apparently since Lollipop all buttons get drawn on top of the view, no matter where they are in the hirarchy.

You can deactivate this by adding

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

to the Button in the xml file.

Comment: one more thing this will work if the frame layout is after the button in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

call yourFrameLAyout.bringToFront();

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, that didnt work. I think the FrameLayout is already at the front, since its the last view in the xml file (within the parent view)

Comment: Works everytime. But weird. If i use ImageButton, i have to do this. But if it's just Button, it shows in front of the fragment